# How to concatenate 2d tensors with 2 different dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation, tensor

I was wondering if it is possible to concatenate two different pytorch tensors with different shapes.
one tensor is of shape torch.Size([247, 247]) and the other is of shape torch.Size([10, 183]). Is it possible to concatenate these using torch.cat() on dim=1?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use broadcasting. That is, to broadcast torch.Size([10, 183]) along dimension 0 (to reach 247) or do it for the other dimensions. For torch.cat to work, you need to have matching dimensions along which you are trying to concatenate.